# How do I allow cross origin request

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am a backend developer and i am providing a spring boot rest API with JWT security to consume for a front end developer who calls the api from local host.So when he calls a POST request he says he gets an CORS error.So I added the part

```
 @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");


        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

But still he gets the error.What may be the cause.Any help is appreciated

```
OPTIONS https:my.domain/url 401 (Unauthorized)
```

when it is a POST request.

Controller code:

```
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {



    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restTemplateUserRegitration")
    private RestTemplate restTemplateUserRegitration;
@RequestMapping(value="${user.endpoint}",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody Model ModelRequest){

                Map<String, Object> Status=new HashMap<String, Object>();
                FeedBackStatus = restTemplateUserRegitration.postForObject("http:serviceurl",registration/single",Model.class,Map.class );
                return ResponseEntity.ok(Status); 
    }
}
```

Comment: [See this link](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/) it might help and [this link](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) too

Comment: Clear problem statement. Relevant Code. No *irrelevant* code. Gosh, it's...a good question! (@joker21: they're just relatively rare, it seems, from newer members. Nice one.)

Comment: I think that the problem is on the server side, that it has not CORS activated, so even setting up your header you can't do the call.

Comment: @canillas: The OP is *talking* about the server side. Indications: *"I am a backend developer and i am providing a spring boot rest API..."* Quotes Java code. Writing to a response.

Comment: What debugging have you done? For instance, is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` you're sending back (from `request.getHeader("Origin")`) correct? Are there other headers being sent with the request that you haven't allowed?

Comment: @t-j-crowder i'm talking about the server (WL, Tomcat...) In my case,my app have an API that is exposed to the front, but the server where is deployed (WL8) have no CORS, so it's impossible to call the WS. I have to use the firefox extension to emulate the CORS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the initial request is to get a JWT token then then subsequent calls are having the token as a header

Comment: `OPTIONS https:my.domain/url 401 (Unauthorized)` doesn't look like a CORS error at all (just an error related to the `OPTIONS` call the browser makes for a cross-origin resource). You need to find out why the `OPTIONS` call is failing your authorization requirements and not, I suspect, even making it to your code above.

Comment: Actually my controller is POST method but then y is OPTIONS being called

Comment: @joker21: *"the initial request is to get a JWT token"* I don't see how that relates to any comment of mine above...?

Comment: @joker21: Right, because that's how CORS works. If the POST will be cross-origin, first the browser does an OPTIONS call to see if the POST should be allowed. The error you're quoting indicates an authorization failure (not related to CORS) on that OPTIONS call.

Comment: The "the initial request is to get a JWT token"  is POSt and works fine but then the subsequent only does not works

Comment: @joker21: I suspect you'll find you have that backward. Again: If it's a cross-origin POST, *first* the browser sends OPTIONS, and then if the headers are right, it sends the POST.

Comment: CORS can be handled at your `@RestController` itself. It would be helpful if you could also post your controller code

Comment: No the difference between the two calls is one need token(Second Call) and other does not (login).

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar experience. We have solved the problem as follows.
This code added in securityConfiguration. 
The browser will send the OPTIONS request first before sending the POST request. Therefore, when the request is sent, the authorization header value is not included in the request header, so the JWT filter judges that the user is unauthenticated.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this first, this should allow all origins, but it is security risk.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: The OP is clearly allowing the origin the call came from, which is correct.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Genuine question, what would be the difference from setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the same value as getHeader("Origin") ?

Comment: @jontro: Probably not a significant one. The point above is that the OP is already setting the header to a valid value (almost certainly), so this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option. Not sure if its an elegant one

```
 @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
  }
```

Put this in any spring bean.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Why does the OP need to do this? Code dumps are not *useful* answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own CorsConfiguration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource = new CorsConfigurationSource() {
    @Override
    public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:63342");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET"));
        corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        return corsConfiguration;
    }
};
```

And add it to configuration.

```
.and().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource);
```

And try using this annotation

```
@CrossOrigin
```

Answer (score -1):

You should implement a filter like this:

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.info("Adding CORS Headers ........................");        
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
         res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else { 
         chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }        
    }
}
```

Found this from the post [Cross Origin Request Blocked Spring MVC Restful Angularjs](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/cross-origin-request-blocked-spring-mvc-restful-angularjs.html)

Hope this help!